Clean way to handle formatting `TimeSpan` with variable output?
Is there a way to format a TimeSpan such that it only outputs "necessary" information? Right now, I have
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
@$"{duration:mm' min 'ss\.f' sec'}" == "01 min 30.0 sec"

That works great, but ideally I'd remove the min for times less than a minute, and add an hour for times greater than 60 minutes (right now it "overflows").
The only thing I can think of is
if (duration > TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
{
    WriteLine(@$"{duration:dd' days 'hh' hours 'mm' min 'ss\.f' sec'}");
}
else if (duration > TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
{
    WriteLine(@$"{duration:hh' hours 'mm' min 'ss\.f' sec'}");
}
else if (duration > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
{
    WriteLine(@$"{duration:mm' min 'ss\.f' sec'}");
}
else
{
    WriteLine(@$"{duration:ss\.f' sec'}");
}


There is something called "conditional formatting" apparently: in an answer on a similar question. I don't know if it still works.

Also check out Humanizer Library.
